# WPF MVVM Combobox SelectionChanged/SelectedItem

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am building a WPF App using MVVM and a mySql database. I am having a difficult time getting the `SelectedItem` from a ComboBox stored in a Property. Basically, at this point, I would like the `SelectedItem` displayed in a Textbox. That will help me understand the Binding process better, as I'm still learning.

Ultimately, I would like to use the stored value/property as a reference for pulling another value from the DB. Below is some sample code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**VIEW**

```
        <Grid Background="AliceBlue">

        <Label Content="Street Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Height="28"/>
        <Label Content="State" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Height="22"/>


        <TextBox Name="txtStreetAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="119,55,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
                 Text="{Binding StreetAddress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 />
        <ComboBox Name="cboState" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52"
              DisplayMemberPath="StateAbb"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StateAbbList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStateAbb, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              />

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="180,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"
                 Text="{Binding SelectedStateAbb, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 />


    </Grid>
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
public class AddStreetAddressVM : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Add Street Address";
        }
    }

    const string dbConnectionString = @"datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='optest1a1';username=root;password=";

    private ICommand _cboStateAbb;

    private string _streetAddress;
    private ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb> _stateAbbList;
    private string _selectedStateAbb;
    private int _selectedStateNum;

    public ICommand CboStateAbb
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cboStateAbb == null)
            {
                _cboStateAbb = new RelayCommand(param => this.fillStateAbb(), null);
            }

            return _cboStateAbb;
        }
    }

    public string StreetAddress
    {
        get { return _streetAddress; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _streetAddress, value, () => StreetAddress); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb> StateAbbList
    {
        get { return _stateAbbList; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _stateAbbList, value, () => StateAbbList);
        }
    }

    public string SelectedStateAbb
    {
        get { return _selectedStateAbb; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedStateAbb, value, () => SelectedStateAbb);
            //if (_selectedStateAbb != null)
            //{
            //    GetStateNum();
            //}

            //_selectedStateAbb = value;
        }
    }

    public int SelectedStateNum
    {
        get { return _selectedStateNum; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedStateNum, value, () => SelectedStateNum); }
    }

    public AddStreetAddressVM() : base()
    {
        StateAbbList = new ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb>();
        fillStateAbb();
    }

    private void fillStateAbb()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            StateAbbList = new ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb>();
            con.Open();
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_states";
            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
            MySqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 1;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string StateAbb = dr.GetString(2);
                tblStateAbb stateabb = new tblStateAbb(count, StateAbb);
                StateAbbList.Add(stateabb);
                count++;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void GetStateNum()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string Query = "SELECT State_Num FROM tbl_states WHERE State_Abb='" + SelectedStateAbb + "' ";
            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
            MySqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 1;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int StateNum = dr.GetInt32(1);
                StateNum = SelectedStateNum;
            }
            con.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

**MODEL - State Abbreviations**

```
public class tblStateAbb : ObservableObject
{
    private Int32 _count;
    private String _stateAbb;
    private Int32 _stateNum;
    private ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb> _tblStateAbb;

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _count, value, () => Count); }
    }

    public String StateAbb
    {
        get { return _stateAbb; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _stateAbb, value, () => StateAbb); }
    }

    public Int32 StateNum
    {
        get { return _stateNum; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _stateNum, value, () => StateNum); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb> StateAbbList
    {
        get { return _tblStateAbb; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _tblStateAbb, value, () => StateAbbList); }
    }

    public tblStateAbb() : base()
    {
        Count = 0;
        StateAbb = "";
        StateAbbList = new ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb>();
    }

    public tblStateAbb(int count, string stateabb) : base()
    {
        Count = count;
        StateAbb = stateabb;
        StateAbbList = new ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb>();
    }

    public tblStateAbb(int count, string stateabb, int statenum) : base()
    {
        Count = count;
        StateAbb = stateabb;
        StateNum = statenum;
        StateAbbList = new ObservableCollection<tblStateAbb>();
    }

}
```

**OBSERVABLE OBJECT (INotifyPropertyChange)**

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        Debug.Assert(GetType().GetProperty(propName) != null);

        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
        {
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, string propName)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propName);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression)expr;
            MemberExpression memberExpr;

            if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
            {
                var unaryExpr = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
                memberExpr = (MemberExpression)unaryExpr.Operand;
            }
            else
            {
                memberExpr = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(memberExpr.Member.Name);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**RELAY COMMAND**

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it is fair that you need help and you are asking us to read all that code you have posted? Please narrow down the issue and only post that part of your code.

Comment: Why not just read the parts you are interested in? If you think I should only post the View, then read just the View and ignore everything else. No?

Comment: Well to be fair, I am not interested in reading any of it. And to be honest most other people are not interested either. The point I am making is that you need to put some effort into your question and make it as easy possible so people would help you. Right now, it is not easy. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try this question... Ignore all of the code above except the View and ViewModel (I'm assuming you need something): " I am having a difficult time getting the SelectedItem from a ComboBox stored in a Property.  All I get is 'OnPoint2a1.Models.tblStateAbb' as the SelectedStateAbb when I select a State from the ComboBox. Any help would be appreciated."

Comment: I think this property `public string SelectedStateAbb` should be `public tblStateAbb SelectedStateAbb`

Comment: Changed to 'tblStateAbb' in Property. Now nothing is displayed in the Textbox where SelectedItem was bound and 'OnPoint2a1.Models.tblStateAbb' was displayed before.  Thoughts?

Comment: As CodingYoshi suggests, change your `SelectedStateAbb` property type to `tblStateAbb` and change your TextBox in XAML to bind to `SelectedStateAbb.StateAbb` or whatever property of your object you'd like to show.

Comment: Got it. I was forgetting to reference the property of my object in XAML. Thank you, Roger!

Comment: Have a look at the differences between SelectedValue, SelectedItem, SelectedValuePath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SelectedStateAbb` is a `string`, you should set the `SelectedValuePath` property of the `ComboBox` to "StateAbb" and bind the `SelectedValue` property to `SelectedStateAbb`:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboState" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52"
        DisplayMemberPath="StateAbb"
        SelectedValuePath="StateAbb"
        ItemsSource="{Binding StateAbbList}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedStateAbb, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="180,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"
         Text="{Binding SelectedStateAbb, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: This works well.  The answers (in original comments) by CodingYoshi and Roger Leblanc also worked. Thank you very much for all of the help and input!  I will try to be more concise with my questions in the future.  Cheers!